# JSON parser with child

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, list, axios

I have this Json file:

```
{  
   "id":0,
   "leagueCaption":"League Two",
   "rankings":[  
      {  
         "id":0,
         "position":1,
         "teamName":"Portsmouth",
         "wins":26,
         "draws":9,
         "losses":11,
         "points":87
      },
      {  
         "id":0,
         "position":2,
         "teamName":"Plymouth Argyle",
         "wins":26,
         "draws":9,
         "losses":11,
         "points":87
      },
      {  
         "id":0,
         "position":3,
         "teamName":"Doncaster Rovers FC",
         "wins":25,
         "draws":10,
         "losses":11,
         "points":85
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to render a list using map, however I can not render it by having the child rankings, 
I need to render the leaguecaption as a Title, and the rankings on the grid,

I did this, but it still is not working, it returns me an error saying that it is not possible to render,

My request:

```
getItems(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ 'isLoading': true });
        API.getRanking(this.state.code)
            .then(items => this.setState({ items, 'isLoading': false }))
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));

}
```

My component:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="pure-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="itemGrid">Position</th>
                            <th className="itemGrid">Points</th>
                            <th className="itemGrid">Name</th>
                            <th className="itemGrid">Wins</th>
                            <th className="itemGrid">Draws</th>
                            <th className="itemGrid">Defeats</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.props.items.map(function (team) {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={team.id}>
                                        <td>{team.position}</td>
                                        <td>{team.points}</td>
                                        <td>{team.teamName}</td>
                                        <td>{team.wins}</td>
                                        <td>{team.draws}</td>
                                        <td>{team.losses}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

My screen render:

```
return (
            <div className="container" >
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>Championship of Football</h1>
                </div>

                <ChampionshipForm 
                    onSubmit={this.getItems}
                    controlId='form'
                    id="code"
                    name="code"
                    value={this.state.code}
                    onChange={this.setCode.bind(this)}
                />

                <RankingTable items={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        );
```

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Are you initializing `state.items` as an empty array `[]`? If you aren't there will be a moment where `map()` is executing against `undefined`, hence the error. Either initialize in the parent component's `state.items` as an empty array `[]` or use defaultProps (empty array) in the child. Or use conditional rendering along the lines of `this.state.items && this.state.items.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. But i am suspecting you are accessing items before its available. Try add a simple checking like below in your component

```
{
   this.props.items && this.props.items.map(function (team) {
        return (
            <tr key={team.id}>
                <td>{team.position}</td>
                <td>{team.points}</td>
                <td>{team.teamName}</td>
                <td>{team.wins}</td>
                <td>{team.draws}</td>
                <td>{team.losses}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    })
}
```

Another possible schenarion is that, `items` is not an array hence the reason why `items.map` is not a function. Can you console `this.props.items` in your component and it type like below

```
console.log(this.props.items);
console.log(typeof this.props.items)
```

the second console from above should print array. If not then you are passing the wrong items type.

One more thing i noticed. Your array is `rankings` and items is a object from your json above. Consider changing

```
 <RankingTable items={this.state.items}/>
```

to

```
 <RankingTable items={this.state.items.rankings}/>
```

Comment: I've ran into this same issue before when first working with reactjs.

Comment: With this solution worked perfectly, thank you for sharing the knowledge!